# jsp session lost after javascript window.replace.location with other jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp, session, redirect

I am developing an web application where I need to redirect to home.jsp page after login.jsp page.I need to use session objects in home page.But whenever I tried to access session objects from home page , but  I am getting null value.How do I access session objects from home page after redirection without losing session.I am redirecting Jsp pages using java script windows.location.replace.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exact reason but
tomcat( or other framework ) doesn't get the session object properly at some point.
It happens sometimes because of Request method, or some other xml configurations.

I believe you checked that the value of <%@page session@> is not false
and none of your jsp invalidates session object or remove attributes of it.

I lost my error record, so I can't tell you why this is happenning
but if you think windows.location.replace is the problem,
then try to use response.sendRedirect( "url" ) in your jsp.

Comment: Solved.Thanks for help.It's the redirecting.I've used jsp page forwarding and some changes to my code and it worked fine.